# How to make popup window in javascript only show once?

Tags: javascript

I want to make single pop up window in javascript. No matter how many times the button is pressed from parent page, only the single pop up is activated.

How can I do that in Javascript?

Comment: What is the purpose of the JSP tag?

Comment: I was going to suggest using a cookie, but I like the other solutions here instead because they don't require Cookies to be enabled which you can't always assume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `window.open` method takes 3 parameters.

- a URL
- a Name
- a list of arguments

As long as the **Name** portion is the same when you open the popup, the same window will be reused.

```
window.open ("http://www.google.com","mywindow","status=1");
```

---

**Here's another idea.**

Why not create an inline page popup (div) with an iFrame inside? [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) does this pretty easily along with a number of other frameworks. Pretty easy to write with custom Javascript as well.

This way your users will never navigate from your window and only that popup will ever live from clicking the button.

Comment: Another idea? It was initially your sole answer :)

Comment: thanks for the tip, I forgot to give the name. thanks to  (http://www.javascripter.net/faq/openinga.htm) too

Comment: @BalusC, I knew there is a way to do it with window.open but wrote my initial answer first while I researched `window.open`.

Answer (score 4):

Just give the window a fixed name. So, don't do

```
window.open('popup.jsp');
```

but do

```
window.open('popup.jsp', 'chooseHereYourFixedName');
```

It will then be reused.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var popup;
</script>
<input type="button" onClick="if (!popup) popup = window.open('new.html');">
```