# how to stop user to open a window which is already opened?

Tags: jquery, window.open

I am developing one website in php. and to display reports and service requests i am using another window. means from menu when user clicks on one report or service request i am opening it into new window.

But the problem is if one report is already opened into a window. and when user clicks on same report from menu than its opening in another new window. so there is two same windows for one page.

so i want to check at the time of opening a window that if that page is already opened in a window than new window won't open. and if not than it will open in a new window.

like
if customer_report.php is already opened than show that window.
else window.open(customer_report.php);

can i check like this ?

how do i have control of opening a new window ?

Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528671/javascript-window-open-only-if-the-window-does-not-already-exist

Comment: please check this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655938/how-to-make-popup-window-in-javascript-only-show-once to check the answer

Comment: @Juhana : i tried that but it didnt work for me.

Comment: @Paniyar : I tried a/c that post but it gives me an error saying winRefs is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem got solved with this post.

[how to prevent reopening new window using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390504/how-to-prevent-reopening-new-window-by-click-event-in-jquery?lq=1)

the second answer worked for me.

Thanks a lott everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp), you can specify a target.

example: window.open(customer_report.php, "myReport");

Comment: ya i tried that but i have urls like this. customer_report.php?id=25 and customer_report.php?id=123. so with the name i cannot open two customer's report at a time. i need to prevent user to open same customer report twice.